# How to get the Parameters for a Lambert conformal conic projection CRS in QGIS 2.6

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am currently having some trouble adding the CRS to a vector file that I want to re project to WGS84/UTM. The shapefile is using Lambert Conformal Conic Projection; ITRF92 horizontal datum and GRS 1980 ellipsoid according to the metadata.

I will like to know how to define the original CRS since in QGIS Lambert CCP/ITRF92 does not appear as part of the available reference systems. The full definition is:

> ```
> GEOCCS["ITRF92",DATUM["International_Terrestrial_Reference_Frame_1992",SPHEROID[‌​"GRS
> 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6651"]],‌​PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9‌​001"]],AXIS["Geocentric
> X",OTHER],AXIS["Geocentric Y",OTHER],AXIS["Geocentric Z",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4914"]]
>
> Projection: Lambert conformal conic  
> Standard parallel: 17.5  
> standard parallel: 19.5  
> longitude of the central meridian: -102.000000 
> latitude of the origin of the projection: +12.000000  
> false easting: 2 500 000
> false northing: 0
> ```

The data's location is in Mexico.

Comment: Well, the given definition is wrong--ITRF92 does not use the Clarke 1866 ellipsoid. Can you post the projection parameters and the data's location? Maybe we can come up with what coordinate system it should be.

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering...this is the info: GEOCCS["ITRF92",DATUM["International_Terrestrial_Reference_Frame_1992",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6651"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Geocentric X",OTHER],AXIS["Geocentric Y",OTHER],AXIS["Geocentric Z",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4914"]]

Comment: Projection: Lambert conformal conic
Standard parallel: 17.5
standard parallel: 19.5
longitude of the central meridian: -102.000000
latitude of the origin of the projection: +12.000000
false easting: 2 500 000
false northing: 0

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS, goto `Settings -> Custom CRS`, and `Copy from existing CRS`.

take a lcc projection based on WGS84, like EPSG:3762

`+proj=lcc +lat_1=-54 +lat_2=-54.75 +lat_0=-55 +lon_0=-37 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`

and replace the values to your system:

`+proj=lcc +lat_1=17.5 +lat_2=19.5 +lat_0=12 +lon_0=-102 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`

I took ITRF92 and WGS84 as identical. See this page for more information about that:

ftp://itrf.ensg.ign.fr/pub/itrf/WGS84.TXT